# Unknown URLs are redirecting to homepage (from www.example.com/page/2345343 to www.example.com)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using a WordPress website and I got this issue, I'm not sure it's an issue or feature in WordPress.

When I enter my website name like [www.example.com/page/1234234](http://www.example.com/page/1234234) (random number) or [www.example.com/page](http://www.example.com/page), it is redirecting to the home page ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).

And also when I enter pagination in URLs like [www.example.com/blog/page2](http://www.example.com/blog/page2) and it is redirecting to [www.example.com/blog/page/2](http://www.example.com/blog/page/2).

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I can't really explain it, but it's a feature, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Its a default wordpress functionality, if you want to change it, you can use filters to change default wp urls

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for that

Comment: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-default-search-url-slug-in-wordpress/  try this